# Adding/Removing hosts file entry using powershell corrupts the file

Tags: windows, powershell, hosts

I'm trying to add or remove a specific entry in Windows hosts file using powershell, but when I do this, it works for some time, and after a while it gets edited again (when Windows reads it, I guess), and it becomes corrupted (displays chinese characters).

I've tried using parts of a code i found [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Modify-Add-Remove-Windows-cd052037).
It allows me to edit the file properly and the entry is effective, until it gets corrupted.

I'm doing this to add the entry:

```
If ((Get-Content "$($env:windir)\system32\Drivers\etc\hosts" ) -notcontains "111.111.111.111 example.com")  
 {ac -Encoding UTF8  "$($env:windir)\system32\Drivers\etc\hosts" "111.111.111.111 example.com" }
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laMfB.png) is what the file looks like after it gets corrupted:

Thanks for your help.

***Solved:***
Remove `-Encoding UTF8`

Comment: Why do you change the encoding for the file append?

Comment: that file is usually ASCII. as with AdminOfThings, i am curious why you are changing the encoding ...

Comment: Honestly, I copied from the example above, I'll try to remove it, or should i specify another encoding ?

Comment: The `*-Content` cmdlets default to ASCII encoding, so just remove the parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working great !

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers *-content encode in ANSI by default and can handle things like accents.

Comment: That should work ok.  I could see using `out-file -append` or `>>` corrupting a file, because those don't check the bom and encode in unicode.

Comment: How do you remove it?

Comment: @js2010 *\*sigh\** Yes, I know. But Microsoft in their infinite wisdom decided it's a good idea to confuse everyone by using both terms synonymously, so I'm sticking with the term that you'd actually pass to the parameter and that is used in the cmdlet help.

Answer (score 3):

Because as it states in the comment of the hosts file, "*The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one space.*", trying to find a string with exactly one space character in between could return false.

I think it would be better to use Regex for this as it allows matching on more than one space character to separate the IP from the host name.
However, this does require the usage of `[Regex]::Escape()` on both parts of the entry as they contain regex special characters (the dot).

Something like this:

```
$hostsFile  = "$($env:windir)\system32\Drivers\etc\hosts"
$hostsEntry = '111.111.111.111 example.com'

# split the entry into separate variables
$ipAddress, $hostName = $hostsEntry -split '\s+',2
# prepare the regex
$re = '(?m)^{0}[ ]+{1}' -f [Regex]::Escape($ipAddress), [Regex]::Escape($hostName)

If ((Get-Content $hostsFile -Raw) -notmatch $re) {
    Add-Content -Path $hostsFile -Value $hostsEntry
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's true, it would be better to do it in order to match all the possibilities, but my goal here was just not to add the entry twice in case this script is called several times, so in this case -notcontains is enough